# Pandas Removing index column

Tags: pandas

When I import a excel as a data frame in pandas and try to get rid of the first column I'm unable to do it even though i give index=None. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: `DataFrames` and` `Series` will always have an index. However, it is NOT considered a column, so your first column is really `'friend'` You can read more about why the index is important [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this, too. You can make the friend column the index instead. That gets rid of the original index that comes with pd.read_excel(). As @ALollz says, a dataframe always has an index. You get to choose what's in it.

`data.set_index('friend', inplace=True)`

See examples in the documentation on [DataFrame.set_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).